# git pull doesn't bring all the changes

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

This question has been asked many times and I have tried solution provided there but no luck for me. So ...

I have master and test_branch

```
Admin@paul MINGW64 ~/my-project (master)
$ git diff master test_branch
```

it shows 5 files and so many commits. 
But when I do:

```
Admin@paul MINGW64 ~/my-project (master)
$ git pull origin test_branch

From https://bitbucket.org/clientname/my_project
 * branch            test_branch -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging page/test1.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in page/test1.java
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I fix the conflicts , run tests and get failure because pull didn't bring all the changes and for file test1.java only 1 or 2 lines of conflict not all.

I tried `gitk` too but that shows very complex web kind of structure which is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you're `pull`ing into `master` rather than your local `test_branch`? Typically if the remote has new `test_branch` changes, you would want to do:

```
git checkout test_branch
git pull origin test_branch
```

If you're trying to bring `test_branch` changes into `master`, that operation is typically done locally using `merge` rather than `pull`.

Comment: `Admin@paul MINGW64 ~/my-project (master)
$ git merge origin test_branch` it shows conflict with one branch only.

Comment: So `git merge origin test_branch` is actually trying to execute two merges: one with `origin`'s default branch (likely `origin/master`) and one with `test_branch`. The former is probably a no-op, but thought you should know.

If you have conflicts, you have conflicts. Without more information, we won't be able to assist with helping you resolve them, if that's where your problem is.